# Can I use URLs in the Open File dialog?

Tags: pantheon-files, files

When using the file dialog in Windows it's possible to specify a URL instead of a local file. Is it at all possible to do this in elementary OS? When trying what's in the image below, it simply does nothing when clicking open. I'm running the latest ISO from the site.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "no" - not at the moment. You can access remote files and folders using addresses such as ftp://user@example.com/...  or through WebDAV shares but you cannot use it like a web browser.

Comment: I don't believe ajwilson is asking to use Pantheon Files as a web browser, they are asking if you can enter a URL in the Open File dialog and use that.

Comment: The file chooser dialog has the same capabilities as the standard Gtk FileChooser at the moment although it has Pantheon Files style breadcrumbs (for Gtk3 programs).  The filechooser dialog does not currently cope with web addresses typed into the pathbar.  If you have remote locations mounted in the sidebar then you can use that to navigate to those locations and open files there.  I said "like a web browser" not "as a web browser" meaning it cannot open files on a web server.

Comment: I believe this remains an accurate answer.